# Why is it possible to set a private member on an object instance, of the same class within an object?

Tags: php

Can anybody explain why I'm able to set the private member `$bar` in `TestFoo::getFooInstance()`?

`TestFoo::getFoo2Instance()` however returns a fatal error.

I always assumed that private members should only be accessible from the same object instance rather than same object class?

```
<?php

class TestFoo  {

    private $bar;

    public static function getFooInstance()
    {
        $instance = new TestFoo();
        $instance->bar = "To bar or not to bar";
        return $instance;
    }

    public static function getFoo2Instance()
    {
        $instance = new TestFoo2();
        $instance->bar = "To bar or not to bar";
        return $instance;
    }

    public function getBar()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}

class TestFoo2 {
    private $bar;
    public function getBar()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}

$testFoo = TestFoo::getFooInstance();
echo $testFoo->getBar();

// returns PHP fatal error
//$testFoo2 = TestFoo::getFoo2Instance();
//echo $testFoo2->getBar();
?>
```

Comment: I was always been confused about the same, but it seems it need to be that way in order to have different instances inwithin the class, or to realize singletons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea behind `protected` and `private` attributes is that a class wants to hide those from outside code. Not as a measure of security, but because those attributes are for class internal use only and are not supposed to be a public interface for other code. Anything that is `public` can be used by other code and should remain unchanged to prevent other code from breaking. `private` and `protected` attributes and methods can only be used by the class itself, so if you need to refactor or change them the changes are guaranteed to be localised to the class itself and you're guaranteed not to break anything else.

So a class is allowed to modify the attributes and call the methods of *any* object instance of its type, because the class itself can be trusted to know about its own implementation.