# Why am I able to access private properties inside a deep cloned class in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, clone, deep-copy, private-members

For what I'm doing this is actually fine, but I'm wondering how I'm able to access the private property of a deep cloned `$this`. Is it just because I'm still within the same class?

```
class Handler
{
    /** private property **/
    private $stuff;

    /** deep clone **/
    public function __clone()
    {
        $this->stuff = clone $this->stuff;
    }

    /** able to access private property **/
    public function handle()
    {
        $handler = clone $this;
        var_dump($handler->stuff); 
    }
}
```

From what I understand of deep cloning I'm creating an entirely separate object or "entry" in memory, so `$handler` and its `$stuff` is not referenced in the same place in the memory. Even though `stuff` is private I'm still getting an output from `var_dump()`.

I found this concept in [Zend Stratigility](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-stratigility/blob/master/src/MiddlewarePipe.php#L77) line 77.

Comment: `var_dump` is for debugging - it is essential in debugging to find out as much as possible.

Comment: Can you actually access the `private` properties using `$myVar = $handler->stuff; var_dump($myVar);`?

Comment: @MrGlass yes I was able to assign `private $stuff` to the variable `$myPrivate` and `var_dump($myPrivate)` as well. The property type is an `SplQueue`, does that make any difference?

Comment: "public function handle()" is public. i dont understand your question. what do you expect? "deep" is incorrect, its a simple clone and stuff is a cloned object like you implement it. check my own request to get in touch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968371/php-cloning-objects-one-cloned-object-then-contains-not-a-cloned-object-howto

Comment: @fb The handle method is public, but the property I'm accessing is not, it's private. You can see it here too in [Zend Stratigility](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-stratigility/blob/master/src/MiddlewarePipe.php#L77) line 77

Comment: The context of $this is within the same class as the private variable. Maybe php is smart enough to know the clone is of the same class as well. Would it work if you cloned an instance of the object outside of the class or returned the clone object from the handler function?

Comment: @JPark I can confirm that it doesn't work outside the class, I get a `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property`.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21512591/5749974) does answer my question, I had no idea about this concept, thanks!

Comment: Hi Timothy: Your class Handler{} owns private members. Only an instance (new Handler()) onws the parts of private properties. A new instance doesnt (e.g: next new Handler() ). function handle() will return or output private properties form an instance. Thats the way.